# angularjs window.alert() while using mouseEvents causes error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the link to the code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/usrmiNkj5YJY5SlV8ETw?p=preview

Open up your javascript console and click on "say hi". It will trigger an error that $apply is already in progress.

But when you remove this piece of code:

```
ng-controller="mouseEvents" ng-mousedown="onMouseDown()" ng-mouseup="onMouseUp()" ng-mousemove="onMouseMove()"
```

and after saving when you click on "say hi" the error is gone.

How can I solve this?

I need the mouseEvents to set flags if the mouse is down or if it is up for multiple different controllers. I can not simply remove it in my code.

**Edit:**

Newer angular version **solved my issue** without $timeout v1.3.10 or higher

Comment: I don't see any error message in the console, neither in Chrome(27)  nor in FF(32).

Comment: Are you using alert in your original code as well? http://plnkr.co/edit/sLdVSX?p=preview

Comment: @PSL yes I am, do you see error messages?

Comment: @t.niese I am using chrome version 37 and disabled all my extension. I can see it, can you try it with chrome version 37?
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/4kmg4w

Comment: @Ismail sorry I wrote 27 instead of 37.

Answer (score 8):

Use $timeout to let angular finish dirty checking then show the alert.

```
app.controller("demoController",function($scope,$window, $timeout){
  $scope.save = function(){
    $timeout(function(){
       window.alert("hi!");
    });

  };
});
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Kxbey5Rc43xsB9v5ugZ5?p=preview

Comment: It works! Can you give an link or explain more deeply about why it works and why I had the error? Did you see the error too before using $timeout?

Comment: I don't think it is an good practice to use $timeout each time I want to use window.alert()

Comment: This is because you have trigged movedown/up event on click. Whenever a alert box is displayed browser stops the further execution of javascript until user responds, if angular dirty checking is in progress then it gives you error. I assume you don't want show alert on production then $timeout won't be needed.

Comment: Use console.log in place of window.alert for debugging purpose. It won't require $timeout, and also a good practice to follow.

Comment: it is not for debugging purposes, I will use it in production to. There must be some kind of solution or someone else who has encountered the same problem